# Как лучше делать выборку?

Tags: php, выборка

Задача следующая - нужно максимально быстро и безопасно в плане нагрузки генерировать большое количество (около 1 млн.) html файлов на лету и сохранять их на диск.

Файлы генерируются на основе шаблона и строк текста. По 30-50 строк на файл.

Вопрос: откуда лучше делать выборку этих строк (можно подряд идущих) из БД или же из txt файла, чтобы скорость выборки и генерации была наиболее высокой и от нагрузки не падал сервер?

При генерации каждого файла - идет новая выборка этих 30-50 строк.

Comment: А вы уверены, что вам действительно нужен 1млн статических файлов, как бы принято изменяющиеся страницы генерить в момент обращения пользователя к серверу, на лету и никуда не сохранять (разве что кешировать часто использующиеся). И надеюсь вы понимаете, что файловая система очень сильно тормозит если в одной папке более 500 файлов. Кроме того на unix системах есть ограничение на кол-во файлов в файловой системе и оно закончится гораздо быстрее чем место на диске

Comment: Т.е. лучше всю информацию помещать в базу, скажем в SQlLite?

Comment: Ну если вы действительно хотите оставить файлы на диске, то лучше грузить строки заранее в оперативную память, а откуда уже не имеет значение. А если генерить страницы во время обращения, то да, лучше всего в БД, что бы было легче искать требуемые строки